# OpenMP doesn't speed up

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I was trying to make matrices multiplication and counting sort using OpenMP but adding processors didn't speed things up (which was my goal). So I decided to make a simple example and it turned out that even that simple for loop doesn't speed up! So my question is, why this code does not speed up?

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
int num_threads = 4;
long num_numbers;

char* size = argv[1];
char* threads = argv[2];
num_numbers = atoi(size);
num_threads = atoi(threads);

double start_time = clock();
int i =0;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num_threads) default(none) private(i) shared(num_numbers)
for(i =0; i < num_numbers; i++){
    //nothing
}

double end_time = clock();
double result_time = (end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time: %f\n", result_time);

return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling by:

```
gcc -fopenmp -Wall openmp.c -o openmp.o
```

And launching:

```
./openmp.o 500000000000 2
```

Time:

```
1 thread:  4.0s
2 threads: 5.0s
3 threads: 5.4s
```

Why program doesn't speed up?

**Solution:
I changed clock() to omp_get_wtime() and now it speeds up.**

Comment: If that loop truly does nothing, the compiler will be optimising it out entirely.

Comment: It truly does nothing, What can I put in there to test it out?

Comment: You could add an accumulator variable and just add `i` each time. Mathematically it can be optimised but I'm pretty sure the compiler isn't that smart

Comment: Create 2 arrays and perform array addition. That's the simplest thing I can think of. Then try more challenging algorithms.

Comment: I added sum variable outside the pragma block, added it to the private(), and in the for loop: sum += i; It did not change anything i.e. it still does not speed up

Comment: It's been a while since I used OpenMP, but I think you're unnecessarily sharing `num_numbers`. Anything you share will reduce the benefits of threading. In fact, to update my suggestion, you should have a sum array (with one element for each thread). Zero all of them at the start, then inside the loop update the element corresponding to the current thread (OpenMP has a method to get this). After the loop, add the values in each bucket to get the final answer. With that, you need no sharing, and you should see the performance benefits.

Comment: Also I believe that if you declare `i` inside the loop (`for( int i; ...`) instead of before it and making it private, it will be a bit more optimal (it's better practice at least; as it is, the value of `i` after the loop could be anything)

Comment: I cant declare like that in C...

Comment: [link](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_workshare1.c) this examplary code doesn't speed up either...

Comment: OK, then I have to ask: are you sure your machine actually has multiple cores? (though, I'd remove the printf line in that code before benchmarking!)

Comment: Yep I removed printf, Yes I've got Core i5, and also tested on 4 core machine on which I've been running MPI programs successfully.

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately, some compilers are that smart. And they are definitely smart enough to realize if that counter is not used afterwards. If you want to benchmark with optimizations turned on, you must actually print the resulting value (after stopping the time), or do something else with it so that the optimizer realizes that it is not supposed to optimize the loop away.

Comment: And yet another `clock()`-does-not-measure-wall-time-on-Unix question. Also, that big number overflows `atoi()` - you need `atol()`.

Comment: I changed clock() to omp_get_wtime() and now it speeds up. Thanks.